# Creating a git alias containing bash command substitution and an argument

Tags: bash, git, git-alias

Got this:

`git diff $(git status -s | awk 'FNR == $LINE_NUM {print $2}')`

...where line number is the file output by status.

Now I want to create an alias for this command in `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
diff-num = $WHAT_SHOULD_I_PUT_HERE?
```

I want this alias to run git's diff command based on the line number argument I'll type in on the command line. I'm new to bash and I'm not sure if I need a bash function to handle this or how to pass the argument into the substituted command.

Comment: I think I need an awk.script file to get a variable into the awk command.

Answer (score 3):

The usual form for this is to use the conventional `!` shell escape, define an arbitrarily-named shell function and run that, git supplies it with your args. One of my goto's is `lgdo`,

```
git config alias.lgdo '!f() { git log --graph --decorate --oneline "${@---all}"; }; f'
```

also, I have `gr` and `grl` as `git config --get-regexp {,--local}` aliases:

```
[alias]
        grl = "!f() { git config --local --get-regexp \"${@-.}\"; }; f"
        gr = "!f() { git config --get-regexp \"${@-.}\"; }; f"
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that while hunting for an answer to this. I already have the function written in a bash script. There's a nice advantage to be able to see the script on multiple lines so I'm going to stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it worked out. Git alias looks like this:

```
diff-num = ! diff_num
```

Bash function is this:

```
diff_num () {
    line=${1:-1}
    git diff $(git status -s | awk 'FNR == '$line' {print $2}')
}
```

Function must be exported with the following bash command in your bash config file:

`export -f diff_num`